# How to design car buzzer alarm with minimal current consumption of 12V battery?

Tags: automotive, piezo-buzzer

Could you please help me to design Car alarm buzzer circuit using relay, and Input of the relay and buzzer should be +12 volts from car battery. when i have searched about some circuits and buzzer its mentioned like "Sound Output:Min. 85±5dB at 12V DC , what it means and i need to determine very minimal current consume buzzer part.

Comment: You want minimal current consumption yet you use a relay. Unless you will be using a bi-stable relay the relay will consume power when it is on. 85dB at 12 V is the sound pressure level of the buzzer when excited with 12V. You want to use a piezo based buzzer, these are very loud but consume little power.

Comment: You seem to focus on minimizing the current *while buzzing*, wich makes no sense to me: that situation should not last too long, and a half-decent 25AH battery can keep a buzzer buzzing for hours if not days. IMO you should focus on minimal current consumption in the "armed but no-alarm" state.

Answer (score 1):

hi thanks for your kind reply it is useful for me. And i have designed the circuit for car buzzer alarm. Transistor Q3 base pin power up by Gpio pin 3.3V IO voltage and i have used terminal block 2 pin connector for buzzer connection. Could you please help me to verify it?
[image]

Comment: That seems right.

Answer (score 0):

Relay coils can consume a lot of current - not usually a problem from a car battery but wasteful.

As Fakemoustache has pointed out some form of bistable circuit would be needed so you can switch the buzzer on, leave it on and then reset. This could be done with a relay.

A very simple bistable circuit can be made from two NAND gates from a 4011 CMOS IC. Being CMOS the current consumption is very low.  The buzzer can be controlled by either a MOSFET or BJT (acting as a switch).

[image]

A few refinements:

R3 and C1 act as a filter- cars tend to have spikes on their 12V supply. Take the +ve supply to the 4011 from this junction. C2 slightly delays the RESET input when first powered up so the buzzer will be OFF. R7 and LED is an optional visual indicator that the buzzer has been triggered. R5 just helps SW2 contacts by reducing the initial current as C2 discharges.

The set and reset inputs don't have to be physical switches. Worth experimenting with different types of trigger circuit.